# How to structure a monorepo with Flask, SQLAlchemy (SQLite) and Scrapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, scrapy

I'm building a series of crawlers in [Scrapy](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/index.html) which output I'm saving to a local SQLite database via [SQLAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) as the ORM.

At the same time, I want to expose the scraped data via a web interface for which I'm currently using [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/).

I am relatively new to Python and I got stuck on how to make the same SQLAlchemy models available to both the Scrapy spiders and the Flask endpoints and templates.

My project structure looks like this:

[image]

Here's how I initialise SQLAlchemy in Flask:

```py
# app.py
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from models import db, Store

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///db.sqlite3'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db.init_app(app)
```

And these are my models:

```py
# models.py
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from dataclasses import dataclass

db = SQLAlchemy()


@dataclass
class Store(db.Model):
    id: int = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name: str = db.Column(db.String)

# ...
```

I have tried importing `models.py` in Scrapy by using:

```py
# stores/spiders/discovery.py
import sys

sys.path.append("../..")
from ...models import Store
```

But regardless of what path I append, I'm getting an error:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
Could not load spiders from module 'stores.spiders'. See above traceback for details
```

How can I make SQLAlchemy available to both Flask and Scrapy while keeping all code in a monorepo?